# How to disable automatic scrolling?

Tags: jquery, scroll, squarespace

I have a webpage in SquareSpace, and whenever you click on any of the gallery pages, it automatically scrolls down past the header. Check it out here: https://kathrynbrylinsky.squarespace.com/#/sowsticks-/

I tried to disable it by placing the following code in the footer (and including the jQuery library in the header):

```
<script>
  $( document ).ready(function() {
    $( "a.project" ).click(function() {
      $(window).scrollTop(0);
      console.log("hi");
    });
  });   
</script>
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `e` param to click function to get the event click object and then call `e.preventDefault()`

```
<script>
  $( document ).ready(function() {
    $( "a.project" ).click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(window).scrollTop(0);
      console.log("hi");
    });
  });   
</script>
```

Using `preventDefualt` you stop the default event flow.